# Etymology of the term "journal bearing"

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, bearings

Typically the word "journal" refers to a collection of written records, experiences, or transactions. However, there is a common type of bearing known as a sleeve bearing, radial bearing, or journal bearing.

The terms "sleeve" or "radial" are self-explanatory, but I'm interested in knowing more about the use of the term "journal" for this type of bearing. What is the historical (or mechanical) reason for this naming convention?

Comment: Words can have multiple meanings and engineering words and terms even more so.

Comment: Take a look here, someone else already asked it: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173387/what-is-the-origin-of-journal-to-mean-a-mechanical-shaft

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Interesting! That's the kind of insight I was hoping for.